# Adding audio recordings to a tableviewcontroller and playing the corresponding one when cell is touched

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a ViewController and a TableViewController. I am recording in the ViewController and want to send each recording to the TableViewController and when the user touches a certain cell, it should play the saved recording. It should change the TableVC every time a new recording is sent to it. How do I do this? Also, how do I save each new recording to a new cell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a model for your TableViewController, where you store your recordings, backed by a database or filesystem for record storage.
Inserting to a table is as easy as:

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
```

or

```
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths
```

Comment: Wait, how can I create database for my audio recordings, automatically creating new files as new audio gets recorded?